# Reference for Feynman diagram technique(position space) in Thermal Field Theory

Tags: feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, thermal-field-theory

I am trying to study perturbative expansion of Sachdev-Ye-Kitaev model, where I know that the dominant terms are the Melonic diagrams. I am interested in seeing how perturbative corrections affect the two-point function, and how the graph looks different from free theory(which is basically a constant). Therefore I am looking for the Feynman rules in position-space and how to do the computations correctly on a thermal circle. Does anyone have a reference/review regarding these computations ? I am not much familiar with perturbative techniques in thermal field theory, so a graduate level of explanation would be helpful.